# Integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type -- C++

Tags: c++

I'm attempting [problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) in Project Euler, where I have to find largest product of 13 adjacent digits in a given 1000 digit number. However, I am getting the "Integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type" during compilation. Any idea of how to fix this/work around this error?

This is the code till now:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  unsigned long long double number = 7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450;

  cout << number << endl;
}
```

Comment: The largest value you can get is `9^13 = 2.5 * 10^12` so you can use `long long`

Comment: There is no such thing as `unsigned long long double`

Comment: @AdityaPrakash ah, if you want to store the original number, you'll have to store it in a `string` and then pass through it 13 elements at a time whose product can be stored in `long long`.

Comment: @lucieon Makes sense. I was sure I was wrong while using unsigned long long double but I tried to take the largest data type possible :p

Comment: A numeric value with up to 1000 decimal digits requires at least 3322 bits to represent it.    There is no numeric type (floating point or integral) specified in standard C++ that can hold such a value.     You need to work out some other way to represent such a value.

Comment: @Peter standard doesn't specify maximum size for most types. In theory there could be an implementation with `int` being 3322 bits which would be standard conforming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a string:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string number = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
}
```

Then use the digits to solve your problem.

Comment: A more robust solution would probably use something like Boost.Multiprecision but this is how you do it manually. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @jkeys OP is not trying to do any calculations on this large number itself. OP only needs the digits as the problem suggests. Thus a simple string seems sufficient.